# Show that $C_3 \times C_3$ is not isomorphic to $C_9$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I am trying to show that $C_3 \times C_3$ is not isomorphic to $C_9$. I am new to group-theory so forgive my foolish intuitions. One natural thought I had was to show that they are of differing cardinality but intuitively, why can't we map the elements $c_1,c_2,c_3 \in C_3$ to $C_9$ like this:

$f: C_3 \times C_3 \rightarrow C_9$ defined by $f(c_i, c_j) = c_{i+j} \in C_9$.

Comment: Hint: in $C_3\times C_3$, for every element $x$, you have $x^3=e$. Not true for $C_9$. However, the order (i.e. cardinality) of $C_3 \times C_3$ is $9$ (compute the cardinality of a cartesian product of two finite sets), same as $C_9$.

Comment: If I understand it then, there cannot be an isomorphism $f: C_9 \rightarrow C_3 \times C_3$ because $f(8) = f(2^3) = e_{C_3 \times C_3}$ and therefore the kernel contains more than the identity and therefore is not injective.

Comment: Yes. Or another way to view this is: an isomorphism preserves the order, so an element of $C_9$ of order $9$ cannot have an image (by an isomorphism) in $C_3\times C_3$.

Answer (score 4):

Each isomorphism preserves the orders of elements of the respective groups. But $C_9$ has an element of order $9$ whereas $C_3\times C_3$ does not. Hence they are not isomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

Here are three different, but related, reasons:

- $C_9$ has exactly $2$ elements of order $3$.
  $C_3\times C_3$ has at least $4$ elements of order $3$.
- $C_9$ has exactly $1$ subgroup of order $3$.
  $C_3\times C_3$ has at least $2$ subgroups of order $3$.
- The map $x \mapsto x^3$ is the trivial homomorphism on $C_3\times C_3$ but not on $C_9$.